# Create own theme builder for themes like in bethemes and massive dynamics Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress theme development. I have a collection of themes which i want to develop in wordpress. similarly like [bethemes](http://themes.muffingroup.com/) and [massive dynamics](http://massivedynamic.co/). These themes provide their own theme builder for the theme customization. I know about the theme development but have no knowlege about the theme builder. I want to create my own theme builder for my theme collection. I googled it but found nothing which can help me to take a start. Can anyone share some good resource about it.